# Why am I getting no sound from my Amazon WorkSpace?

Tags: macos, audio, aws

I'm connecting to Amazon WorkSpaces using the [Amazon WorkSpaces Client](https://clients.amazonworkspaces.com/) version 3.0.4.964 but I'm not receiving any audio from the Windows VM. My sound works fine locally (I can play a YouTube video) but when I play the same video in a browser in the WorkSpace, all I hear is silence. I'm using a Bluetooth headset, if that makes a difference. I'm also trying to use a microphone and camera, and those don't seem to be available in the Windows VM either.

How can I troubleshoot sound delivery from my Amazon WorkSpace? Is there something I need to configure in macOS sound settings?

I'm running macOS 10.15.3 (Catalina) on my MacBook Pro.

Comment: is there any upgrade done now from Amazon Workspace side to support external audio connectivity changes when connected to it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Amazon WorkSpaces client uses a **Teradici Virtual Audio Driver** which is initialized with the system Sound settings when the connection is first opened. Whatever Sound device was selected in System Preferences when the connection was established will continue to be the sound device for as long as the session was open.

In my case, I had to disconnect the WorkSpaces client, change the system Sound settings to use my bluetooth headset, then reconnect to WorkSpaces to get my sound working on the bluetooth headset.

Comment: So there is no way at the moment to change audio when Amazon Worspaces are running?